# Refresh recyclerView filled from room with spinner case

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-spinner, android-room, android-livedata

I want refresh my data in RecyclerView, when I select some item in spinner. RecyclerView is placed in fragment in tabbed activity, My RecyclerView filled from room with livedata. I create observer for RecyclerView , but I don't understand how I can change my observer or do something else.
May be I need recreate this tab...
Please, tell me what i can do.

When I create new observer I getting new data in RecyclerView, but when I interact with this data, I see that all my old observers are live and react to my actioins.

How I can query another data from database and pass it to observer or create new observer and delete old?

My Fragment

```
public class AllSitesFragment extends Fragment implements  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


@BindView(R.id.recycler_view)
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@BindView(R.id.tvEmptyMessage)
TextView tvEmptyMessage;

@BindView(R.id.spinner)
Spinner spinner;

private WebSitesViewModel mWebSitesViewModel;
private MyRecViewAdapter adapter;

public AllSitesFragment() {}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_sites, container,  false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    mWebSitesViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(WebSitesViewModel.class);

    adapter = new MyRecViewAdapter(getContext(), mWebSitesViewModel, AllSitesFragment.this );
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Observer
    mWebSitesViewModel.getAllWebSites().observe(this, new Observer<List<WebSites>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<WebSites> webSites) {
            adapter.setWebSites(webSites);


            if (adapter.getmWebSites().size() == 0) {
                tvEmptyMessage.setText(R.string.not_saved_sites);
                tvEmptyMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                tvEmptyMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


    mWebSitesViewModel.getAllWebSites().removeObservers(getActivity());
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:

             // Refresh

            break;
        case 1:

             //Refresh

            break;

    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
}
```

Comment: May be you need to call *adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();* to update data.

Comment: This is not help. When I create new observer I getting new data in RecyclerView, but when I interact with this data, I see that all my old observers are live and react to my actioins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter the results of your `getAllWebSites()` function in your viewModel, so you need a setter in that viewModel to set/update your filter.

You can do it by using a [`MutableLiveData`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MutableLiveData.html) variable in your viewModel, which will be used as parameter to filter your Website collection.

This can be done by using a [switchMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations.html#switchMap(android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData%3CX%3E,%20android.arch.core.util.Function%3CX,%20android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData%3CY%3E%3E)) transformation.

It would be something like this (non-functional, adapt it to your needs) :

**ViewModel**

```
public class SitesViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private final YourManager yourManager;
    private final LiveData<WebSites> webSites;
    private final MutableLiveData<YourItem> yourItemFilter;

    public SitesViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        yourManager = new YourManager();
        yourItemFilter = new MutableLiveData<>();
        webSites = Transformations.switchMap(yourItemFilter, input -> yourManager.getAllWebSites(input));
    }

    public void setYourItemFilter(YourItem filter) {
        yourItemFilter.setValue(filter);
    }

    public LiveData<WebSites> getAllWebSites() {
        return webSites;
    }
}
```

Then in your activity simply set the filter value on item selected :

**Activity**

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            YourItem item = (YourItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            mWebSitesViewModel.setYourItemFilter(item);
            break;
        case 1:
            ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @Yann39 I have a similar case.  How would you go about reloading getAllWebsites, for example if the user press the back button, so they can see the original, unfiltered list?